# svg animation wrong way

Tags: html, css, svg

I currently have this: http://jsfiddle.net/3qzt3hz6/4/

```
.circle{
stroke:green;
stroke-width:10;
    fill:none;
    stroke-dasharray:220 360;   

    stroke-dashoffset:0;

    animation:mymove 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
    0%{
        fill:tomato;
    }
    100%{
        fill:tomato;
    stroke-dasharray:0 360;
        stroke-dashoffset:10;
    }
}
```

I was wondering how I could 'reverse' the animation, 
Now it removes the green part, but I want it to create the green part.

So.. it should start without a border, and create the green border instead of starting with the border and removing the border.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
.circle{
        stroke:green;
        stroke-width:10;
        fill:none;
        stroke-dasharray:0 360;   

        stroke-dashoffset:0;

        animation:mymove 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
       0%{
         fill:tomato;
         }
       100%{
        fill:tomato;
        stroke-dasharray:360 0;
        stroke-dashoffset:10;
        }
}
```

Comment: I need the start and stop position of my code to be the exact same.